# Transaction still open even after commiting and closing

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, transactions

First of all, I don't know if that's the best title to explain what my problem is, but here we go: I have a class called `Product` that has an `@OneToOne` mapping on `ProductPriceHistory`.

```
@Entity(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_product", sequenceName="seq_product", allocationSize=1 )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq_product")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="description", length=150)
    private String description;

    @OneToOne
    private ProductPriceHistory price;
    (...)

    public double getPrice() {
        double price = 0.0;

        ProductPriceHistoryDaoImpl productPriceHistoryDaoImpl = new ProductPriceHistoryDaoImpl();

        try {
            productPriceHistoryDaoImpl.beginTx();
            price = productPriceHistoryDaoImpl.getCurrentPriceByProductId(this.id);
            productPriceHistoryDaoImpl.commitTx();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            (...)
        }

        return price;
    }
}
```

As you can see on my `getPrice()` method, I am calling another `Dao` to retrieve the current price for the product. That works OK for a few times, but after calling it like 10x, it looks like the transactions are still open because I get this exception (I guess it's specific from PostgreSQL): `ERROR: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections`.

I've tried this approach: instantiating `ProductPriceHistoryDaoImpl productPriceHistoryDaoImpl`, opening the transaction and closing it OUTSIDE the code that calls `getPrice()` and just pass it by parameter to call the query and this works perfect (slots are not being overloaded as in the 1st approach), but I don't like this approach because I use `getPrice()` inside `.jsp` pages, and I cannot pass `ProductPriceHistoryDaoImpl` by parameter in theses cases.

Adding a little bit more code just to be clearer

```
public class ProductPriceHistoryDaoImpl extends DefaultDaoImpl<ProductPriceHistory>{
    private EntityManager em = HibernateManager.getEntityManager();

    public ProductPriceHistory() {
        super(ProductPriceHistory.class);
    }

    public double getCurrentPriceByProductId(long productId) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

**DefaultDaoImpl.java**

```
public abstract class DefaultDaoImpl<T> {
    private EntityManager em;

    public void beginTx() {
        em = HibernateManager.getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public void commitTx() {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I post it as answer, because I fear that you don't get a better answer. But keep in mind that I am not 100% sure if the following is completly correct.

Hibernate (including other JPA providers) is managing behind the scenes an abstraction layer, used by created EntityManagers. For example it is possible to have more than one EntityManager within the same transaction. At least parts of it are working via tracking of Threads.

In your case, you create a new EntityManager while probably haveing another one created in that Thread and additionally starting & commiting a transaction and closing the EntityManager. What happens in that case exactly is not entirely known to me, but you should change it to the following.
(I may should check out what the jpa spec says for that case, but I assume its not directly covered)

Use exactly the same EntityManager for each combination of transaction and thread. This is can be complicated to manage on your own, thats the reason why nearly ever larger project uses a transaction management system. Well known examples are Spring and JavaEE. 
If youre wana write this EntityManager managing on your own. There are two classes which are handy for doing this. The first one is the Proxy class to intercept calls and redirect to the correct instance. The other one is ThreadLocal for handling the per Thread state.

Answer (score 0):

One quick thought - add some logging to your `DefaultDaoImpl` methods to confirm that your methods are actually being invoked as you expect.

A second observation is that you probably need to provide some information about your (jdbc?) driver: are you using a pooled connection?  Have you considered using one?  Also - why not modify your price DOA to take a collection of items - then you can use one connection for 10 items instead of 10 connections for one item each.